# Is it a good idea to use XML files to present data that is not updated often? VS MYSQL query

Tags: mysql, xml, optimization, web

I'm building my website and I'd like to limit calls to my MYSQL database.

One idea I have is to use XML files to present information that does not need to be updated as regularly as every page load.

Two example are

1. **Site navigation** which might only change once a week.
2. **The number of items in stock** which will in most situations only need to be updated when an item becomes out of stock.

I have a feeling this is a good solution, however my experience with XML is quite limited, so I'd like some feedback before delving into it.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Just use memcache, xcache or any other caching solution to cache your SQL requests.

Comment: Thanks for pointing these out. I had no idea they existed. They are certainly going to help in solving some other performance issues I have.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a good aproach.

Supplying your xml-Files with E-tags forces the Browser to do the caching. So even your Webserver requests could be handled faster.

Comment: This is what I was hoping. Ideally the XML file would be loaded into the cache rather than each time it was called.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use XML for performance reasons, don't do it. Use cache instead, as Märis suggested. If you want to use XML because it is a better primary representation of your model, than by all means, do it ! Be aware that there is a few problems you will have to solve (concurrent edits on your XML files for example).

XML can be a better format to store hierarchical data than a relational database, like your navigation.

Comment: Actually only use of XML is to share data between different systems. For all other uses it's a bad choice.

Comment: I strongly disagree with you. Used correctly, XML can be a good solution to store data as well. The problem is more the filesystem, which doesnt support locking / transactions, ... I could point you to quite a few respectable products that take the XML approach.

Comment: Hmmmm. Everyone makes a good point. Locking/transactions/concurrent edits won't be an issue. The XML files won't be edited. Rather, a new file will created as necessary from information in the database. To give a more specific example, I might have an xml file with tags PRODUCT & AVAILABILITY (values APPLE,AVAILABLE + ORANGE,NOT AVAILABLE). My page would just scan the XML file for the required product and return the availability.

Comment: If the source of your data is a database, you are using XML files as a caching mechanism. In this case, you should go with a caching solution (memcache or other).